# How do I send an email to everyone I've ever sent an email to?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I use Outlook 2003. I want to announce a concert I'm doing. I'd love it if I could simply send an email to everyone I've sent an email to--in other words, every email address in my "sent" folder, ideally including those archived, and ideally sending only one email to each person, even though I may have written many emails to that person.

Is that doable without undue work? Or is there any easy alternative?